# In C# matching all files in a directory using regex

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am currently trying to use the below regular expression in C#

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"-(FILENM01P\\.(\\d){3}\\.PGP)$");
var files = Directory.GetFiles(savePath, "*.PGP")
    .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path))
    .ToList();
foreach (string file in files)
{
    MessageBox.Show(file);
}
```

To match all files that have this file naming convention in a single to directory

```
 FILENM01P.001.PGP
```

If I just load up all files like this

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(savePath, "*.PGP")
foreach (string file in files)
{
    MessageBox.Show(file);
}
```

The I get a string like this; etc.

> C:\Users\User\PGP Files\FILENM01P.001.PGP

There could be many of these files for example

```
FILENM01P.001.PGP
FILENM01P.002.PGP
FILENM01P.003.PGP
FILENM01P.004.PGP
```

But there will never be

```
FILENM01P.000.PGP
FILENM01P.1000.PGP
```

To clarify, only the 3 numbers together will change and can only be between 001 to 999 (with leading zeros) the rest of the text is static and will never change.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to RegEx so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Essentially my end goal is to find the next number and create the file and if there are no files then it will create one starting at 001 and if it gets to 999 then it returns 1000 so that I know I need to move to a new directory as each directory is limited to 999 sequential files. *(I'll deal with this stuff though)***

Comment: Use one of the online regex helper websites (Google "C# online regex helper"). They can help you craft and test a regex.

Comment: why do you have the dash at the beginning?  Also you don't have to escape backslashes in verbatim strings.

Comment: @juharr The reason for the - at the beginning was because I was following an online guide, i.e. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) and they have this pattern: **-\d{3}$** with its description saying **The match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the line or string.**

Comment: That comment in MSDN is related to the trailing `$` symbol. In their sample the `-` actually is matching for negative numbers.

Comment: @user692214  couple of people have provided solution for you. Care to either say if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
var reg = new Regex(@"FILENM01P\.(\d{3})\.PGP");

var matches = files.Select(f => reg.Match(f)).Where(f => f.Success).Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.Value.Split('.')[1])).ToList();

var nextNumber = (matches.Max() + 1).ToString("D3"); // 3 digit with leading zeros
```

Also you might need a if check to see if the next number is 1000 if so then return 0.

```
(matches.Max() + 1 > 999? 0:matches.Max() + 1).ToString("D3")
```

---

My test case.

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
files.Add(@"C:\Users\User\PGP Files\FILENM01P.001.PGP");
files.Add(@"C:\Users\User\PGP Files\FILENM01P.002.PGP");
files.Add(@"C:\Users\User\PGP Files\FILENM01P.003.PGP");
files.Add(@"C:\Users\User\PGP Files\FILENM01P.004.PGP");
```

The output is

```
nextNumber = "005";
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"FILENM01P\.(\d+)\.", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var fnumbers = Directory.GetFiles(src, "*.PGP", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Select(f=>regex.Match(f))
                .Where(m=>m.Success)
                .Select(m=>int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
int fileNum = 1 + (fnumbers.Any() ? fnumbers.Max() : 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"FILENM01P\.(\d{3})\.PGP");

var matches = files.Select(f => reg.Match(f)).Where(f => f.Success).ToList();

var nextNumber = matches.Any()
    ? matches.Max(f => int.Parse(f.Groups[1].Value)) + 1 
    : 1;
```

Where `files` is a list of the files to match.

Comment: is `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` not just `\d{3}`?

Comment: @LeeCampbell Yep you're right -had a mental slip (originally it was `[0-9][0-9][1-9]` before I realized I wasn't paying attention). Editing now.. Thanks :)